# Full text search in SQL Server 2008 : add new stopword to existing stop list

Tags: full-text-search, stop-words

I am doing a FTS in SQL Server 2008.

I need to add some new stop words (there are about 100) to existing stop list at once.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [TableName.CatalogName] ADD 'NewStopWord' LANGUAGE 'Neutral';
```

Obviously you need to replace `'NewStopWord'` with your word.  You can also change `'Neutral'` if you want to make the stop word language specific.  Rinse.  Repeat.

One more note.  In SQL 2008 you can only specify the `[TableName]` but in SQL 2012 you can specify `[TableName.CatalogName]`.  This makes sense since in 2008 you can only have ONE fulltext catalog per table/view.

Answer (score 0):

As taken directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

1. In Object Explorer, expand the server.
2. Expand Databases, and then expand the database in which you want to create the full-text stoplist.
3. Expand Storage, and then right-click Full-Text Stoplists.
4. Select New Full-Text Stoplist.
5. Specify the stoplist name.
6. Optionally, specify someone else as the stoplist owner.
7. Select one of the following create stoplist options:

   - Create an empty stoplist
   - Create from the system stoplist
   - Create from an existing full-text stoplist
8. For more information, see New Full-Text Stoplist (General Page).

Click OK.

Comment: Thank you. This is okay.
But, I want to know how to add many stop words at onece to a stop list.

Right, now we can add stop word one-by-one using ALTER command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
Create table StopListCustome (StopListCustome nvarchar(50))

BULK INSERT dbo.StopListCustome
FROM '\\SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\data\StopList.csv' --you can use other type of insert
WITH ( FORMAT='CSV');

SELECT 'ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST MyStoplist ADD ' + 
    quotename(StopListCustome, '''') + ' LANGUAGE ''English'''
FROM  StopListCustome
```

Then `copy & past` result in new query window and run it. If you use `while` for insert is better than copy past like me ,you can write select query in Cursor .